# Why is the community user awarding bounties?

Tags: support, bounty-awards, community

[This answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/124770/20065) was awarded 25 points by the [community user](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community). How does it happen?
Which answers are awarded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the bounty expires, half of it is awarded automatically to the highest voted answer since the bounty was set. From the [blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/):

> If the bounty owner does not award the bounty within the 7 day bounty period, the same auto-award rules apply, as before: any answers to the question posted after the bounty started, with at least 2 upvotes, are eligible for auto-accept and earn half the bounty amount. If there aren’t any answers meeting that criteria, no bounty is awarded.

The question's [revision history](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/124429/revisions) shows a 50 rep bounty set on Dec 13 at 1:53, and the answer's [revision history](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/124770/revisions) shows the 25 rep awarded on Dec 21 at 3:51.

Comment: OR Community attained sentience :)

Comment: So, the community user automatically award expired bounties?

Comment: Yeap, if there are answers meeting the criteria... The blog post explains everything on the bounty system...